df['col_name'].astype('string') raises error in pyright
I recently added pyright to my project and I'm facing this issue.
import pandas as pd

# Define the cleanup function
def cleanup(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df['col_name_1'] = df['col_name_1'].astype('string')
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col_name_2'])
    return df

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {'col_name_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'col_name_2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cleanup(df)

Errors:
error: "astype" is not a known member of "None" (reportOptionalMemberAccess)
error: Expression of type "DataFrame | None" cannot be assigned to declared type "DataFrame"

This code snippet works perfectly as expected. It's just the pyright type mismatch that is an issue
I'm using the latest version of pyright.
pyright==1.1.357
Steps to reproduce the issue.

Save the above code snippet in pandas_testing.py.
In your cli, run pyright pandas_testing.py

NOTE: Pandas works perfectly fine. This is an issue I'm facing with pyright.

for me this code runs without error

Which pyright version did you use? Can you update to the latest one?

I'm using the latest version. pyright==1.1.357

Can you then show the full code to reproduce the error? And what is your pandas version? I didn't get any error using the command line tool.

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that Pyright, a static type checker, is not able to infer the correct type of the DataFrame column. When you access a column of a DataFrame like df['col_name_1'], Pyright is not able to determine that this is a Series and assumes it could be None, hence the error.
One way to solve this is to use the loc function to access the DataFrame column. This way, Pyright can infer that the result is a Series and not None. Here's how you can modify your code:
def cleanup(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.loc[:, 'col_name_1'] = df.loc[:, 'col_name_1'].astype('string')
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col_name_2'])
    return df

Another way is to use # type: ignore comment to suppress the Pyright error on a specific line:
def cleanup(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df['col_name_1'] = df['col_name_1'].astype('string')  # type: ignore
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col_name_2'])
    return df

However, using # type: ignore should be your last resort as it suppresses the type checker, which could potentially hide real issues.
2nd Error -
The second error is also related to Pyright's type inference. When you use the drop_duplicates method, Pyright is not able to infer that the result is always a DataFrame. It thinks the result could be None or a DataFrame, hence the DataFrame | None type.
To fix this, you can use an assert statement to tell Pyright that the result of drop_duplicates is not None. Here's how you can modify your code:
def cleanup(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.loc[:, 'col_name_1'] = df.loc[:, 'col_name_1'].astype('string')
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col_name_2'])
    assert df is not None
    return df

This assert statement will have no effect at runtime if the condition is true. If the condition is false (which should never happen in this case), it will raise an AssertionError. This gives Pyright the hint it needs to know that df is not None after the drop_duplicates call.

This fixes the astype issue. Thank you!
Do you know about the 2nd error by any chance?

Updated for 2nd Answer @SiddharthPrajosh

"# type: ignore" is a quick fix for me. Thanks for sharing

Installing pandas-stubs solved all pandas related typing issues with mypy and pyright.

Except that's not true. To quote the repository README: "The stubs are likely incomplete in terms of covering the published API of pandas."

@InSync There might be some APIs which stubs doesn't cover today, but it was able to solve the typing issues I had.
